# Rascal MPL get line count of file without loading its contents

Tags: count, line, rascal

Is there a more efficient way than

```
int fileSize = size(readFileLines(fileLoc));
```

to get the total number of lines in a file? I presume this code has to read the entire file first, which could become costly for huge files.

I have looked into [IO](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Library/IO/) and [Loc](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Location/) whether some of this info might be saved in conjunction with the file.

Comment: If IO is slow it's worth looking into using the file:/// scheme. That can sometimes make a difference over more opaque schemes such as project::///

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way, unless you'd like to call `wc -l` via util::ShellExec

Apart from streaming the file and saving some memory counting lines is always linear in the size of the file so you won't win much time.

Comment: Yep in hindsight it *must* be the only way, since there is never a way to tell a priori how many `\n`s there are in any file without scanning the whole thing. Leaving it for future reference though, thanks!